# Can I optimise Ravendb for index creation

Tags: ravendb

Hoping someone can help as this is not clear from the documentation.

I have a nightly backup/restore of a RavenDb 3.5 database onto a dedicated test server. The test server has 8gb memory and 4 cpus.

Before this can be used several patching scripts needs to be run and the indexes rebuilt.

The patching runs fine but the map/reduce index rebuilds pretty much grind to a halt with Ravendb cpu usage at around 2-4%. Memory usage is not particularly high either at about 20%-30%. The indexes are not particularly complicated.

Are there any configuration or index settings that I can apply to speed this up as currently it is taking 2 days to rebuild 2 indexes on a 2gb database. The server is dedicated so I can use as much of the resource as possible to achieve this.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.